# Reordering large PDF files using command line tools

Tags: pdf, itext, command-line-interface, pdftk

I'm working with PDF files that have hundreds of forms within them. Each form is 2 pages long, so in most files pages 1-2 is the first form, pages 3-4 is the second form, and so on.

However, there are several PDF files where the page order of the forms are reversed. In these cases, page 1 is the second page of the first form and page 2 is the first page of the first form, page 3 is the second page of the second form and page 4 is the first page of the second form, and so on.

I want to reorder the page order in these files so that the pages are in this sequence: (2(1), 2(1)-2, 2(2), 2(2)-1, 2(3), 2(3)-1,...,2n,2n-1), where n= total number of pages/2.

I've been looking for a way to do this using command line tools such as cpdf, pdftk, etc., but to no avail. The files are quite large so I would like to do it by using command line tools.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see that you have tagged iText. iText is not a command line tool, but you can use it to write your own command line tool in any language in the Java or .NET ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

CIB pdf toolbox of CIB (https://www.cib.de) has a (non free) command line tool version, which supports all possibilities of PDF merging in one run.

Did you try poppler-utils?
i think with the command line tools pdfseparate and pdfunite utilities you can achieve all you want.

- http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pdfseparate/
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pdfunite/

Answer (score 0):

Would it matter to you if the order of the forms inside the PDF is changed? For example if instead of

```
 form1-reversed,
 form2-reversed,
 form3-reversed
```

your resulting file would look like

```
 form3,
 form2,
 form1
```

?

In this case you could just run PDFtk so that it completely reverses *all* the pages of the original file:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat r1-1 output reversed.pdf
```

(Prefixing a page number with the letter `r` references pages in reverse order. That means `r1` is the last page...)

Comment: Why today's serial downvotes for some of my answers, dear unknown StackOverflow user? Care to explain what was wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on an operating system which supports shell scripting (like Bash on Linux or macOS), you can achieve the output of your requested page numbers by something like this (assuming that your `n==10`):

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  echo -n "$(( 2 * ${i} )) ";
  echo -n "$(( 2 * ${i} -1 )) ";
done
```

This will output `2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9`. Now you could use this PDFtk command for re-ordering the pages as you want:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat $(for i in {1..10};do echo -n "$((2 * ${i})) ";echo -n "$((2*${i}-1 )) ";done) output out.pdf
```